# Copying an excel multi line cell into an Indesign table

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I'm creating a booklet with indesign and I am trying to copy data from an excel spreadsheet into an indesign table. I was given an excel spread sheet with the a list of peoples names, their titles and their companies. I have to put a name in one column and then in the other put the company name and their title, as the picture (1) here illustrates:

[image]

Where the problem arises is trying to merge two cells in excel so that they are underneath each other and then paste it into one cell in the indesign table.

[image: Excel]

I tried to combine column C and D (as IN THE PICTURE) and insert a new line between the columns.  (=C1&CHAR(10)&D1)

This worked in Excel but when copying it into indesign they do not go underneath each other but into different cells and they also show " quotation marks around the text.

I know there must be a relatively simple way of doing this in Excel and then copying it into indesign but I have run out of ideas. Can anyone tell me the best way to approach this as I am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's actually much easier to use a table in Indesign which contains the same amount of cells. Then copy/paste and adjust (merge cells) the Indesign table.

Comment: Another trick is to put a nonsense character between `title` and `company` in Excel (in Column D, moving `company` to Column E), and then search/replace for a soft return in InDesign. The quote marks you just have to S/R to remove, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Never use any new line characters in your Excel data. When InDesign comes across a new line character it will begin a new row, and not a new line within the same cell.

You're on the right track concatenating the two columns into one in Excel, but, as Lauren Ipsum suggests, use a placeholder (eg. a tilde '~') instead of the CHAR(10).

Then, copy your Excel data and paste it into an InDesign table. Then `Find/Change` each tilde with a new line character and you're done.